# How to define a mapping of enum members in the enum type?

Tags: python-3.x, enums, metaclass

I have a Python enum like this:

```
from enum import Enum, unique

@unique
class Levels(Enum):
  Unknown = 0
  Warning = 1
  Error =   2

  def __eq__(self, other):    return self.value ==  other.value
  def __ne__(self, other):    return self.value !=  other.value
  def __lt__(self, other):    return self.value <   other.value
  def __le__(self, other):    return self.value <=  other.value
  def __gt__(self, other):    return self.value >   other.value
  def __ge__(self, other):    return self.value >=  other.value

  __MAPPING__ = {
    "warn":   Warning,
    "error":  Error
  }

  @classmethod
  def Parse(cls, value, default=None):
    return cls.__MAPPING__.get(value, default)
```

In this example, I already extracted the mapping into a class member (according to `timeit.timeit()`, its faster).

My problem is now, that the dict values are using the original enum member values (integers) instead of the created enum members (EnumMeta). This is reasonable, because the don't exists, when the dict is constructed.

**How/Where can I hook into the Enum class / EnumMeta class or my own Levels class, to patch the dict, with the created enum members?**

Answer (score 3):

[Only showing the relevant pieces...]

```
@unique
class Levels(Enum):
    Unknown = 0
    Warning = 1
    Error =   2

    __MAPPING__ = {
        "warn":   Warning,
        "error":  Error
   }

    def __init__(self, *args):
        """Patch the embedded MAP dictionary"""
        self.__class__.__MAPPING__[self._name_] = self
```

`__init__` is called for each member after it has been created, so at that point you can update the `__MAPPING__` using the member name as the key.  If you use this pattern a lot you should consider using another decorator:

```
def add_mapping(enum_cls):
    for name in enum_cls.__MAPPING__:
        member = enum_cls.__members__[name]
        enum_cls.__MAPPING__[name] = member
    return enum_cls
```

and in use:

```
@add_mapping
@unique
class Levels(Enum):
    Unknown = 0
    Warning = ...
```

Comment: I improved you solution a bit, because, the intended enum members are values in the dict. So each __init__ call scans the dict and replaces a value (int) by an enum member, if defined in the mapping.

Comment: @Paebbels: Ah, I misunderstood that part.  Simplified your code and updated the decorator.

Comment: @Paebbels: If this is just a performance enhancement why aren't you putting in all the members?  Also, in 3.5 most, if not all, of the performance hit was removed.

Comment: Using both `__MAPPPING__` and `__MAPPING__` is confusing. Also, what is `self._name_`?

Comment: @martineau:  `__MAPPING__` and `__MAPPING__` are the same thing -- what's confusing about it?

Comment: @martineau: `_name_` is where the actual member name is stored -- `name` is actually a read-only property.

Comment: I meant what is defining `_name_`, it's not an argument. One of the mapping names has an extra `P` in it, so they are not the same thing.

Comment: @martineau: Ah, the OP had the extra `P` typo, and I was only successful in duplicating the typo once.

Comment: @martineau:  Correct, `_name_` is not an argument, it's already part of the member by the time `__init__` is called.  (Hence the leading `self.` ;-) ).  It is set by the metaclass.

Comment: Well, `_name_` doesn't didn't seem documented, at least by searching for it the way I do everything else—which is why I asked—however I just now stumbled across one line mentioning it in the "Finer Points" subsection of "How are Enums different".

Comment: Putting __MAPPING__ into the class really freaks out mypy/type checkers, as they (rightfully) assume it's another enum constant - they don't particularly care about the double underscores.

Comment: @RickMoritz: That's a bug in the type checkers.  Double underscore names will never be an enum member.

Answer (score 1):

To build upon [Mr. Furman's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208880/ethan-furman) offering [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37191287/2973538), a map_value(name) method to get the mapping:

```
add_mapping(enum_cls): 
    enum_cls.__MAPPING__ = {e.value: e for e in enum_cls}
    enum_cls.map_value = lambda name, default=None: enum_cls.__MAPPING__.get(name, default)
    return enum_cls
```

Comment: I approved your edit to my answer, thank you for catching that.  Now if we could just get editors to not reject bug-fixes to code they don't understand.  :(